# How to make a reference to a concrete subtype in an abstract method definition

Tags: java, generics

Suppose I have the following definition:

```
public abstract class SomeAbstractClass {
    
    public abstract List<SomeAbstractClass> getNextElements() ;
}
```

If I build a concrete class that extends `SomeAbstractClass` named for instance `SomeConcreteClass` I would like `getNextElements` to have the following signature:

```
public List<SomeConcreteClass> getNextElements()
```

Instead of:

```
public List<SomeAbstractClass> getNextElements()
```

In other words, I would want my abstract definition to have a type depending on the current concrete type. Can it be done ? If so, how ?

Comment: You can add a generic type to your abstract base class and use it for the `getNextElements()` method. However, how will the `getNextElements()` method be used and what types are visible/known to the caller of that method?

Comment: @Progman Yes, I was kinda hoping I wouldn't have to do that. I'm reluctant to define classes like `MyConcreteClass<MyConcreteClass>` especially because it's more generic than I was hoping. Regarding the second part of your comment, how is that relevant ? I suppose we can assume everything is visible to the caller, for simplicity.

Comment: @MrO The issue might be that you can't do this anyway as the consumer of that method might not see the method with the adjusted return type anyway. But that depends on the system you have.

Answer (score 2):

Just use Java generics:

```java
public abstract class SomeAbstractClass<T extends SomeAbstractClass> {
    public abstract List<T> getNextElements() ;
}
```

```java
public class SomeConcreteClass extends SomeAbstractClass<SomeConcreteClass> {
    @Override
    public List<SomeConcreteClass> getNextElements() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Another possibility would be to use only generic methods as follows:

```java
public abstract class SomeAbstractClass {
    public abstract <T extends SomeAbstractClass> List<T> getNextElements();
}
```

```java
public class SomeConcreteClass extends SomeAbstractClass {
    @Override
    public List<SomeConcreteClass> getNextElements() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

The downside of this is that you now have an unchecked conversion at `List<SomeConcreteClass> getNextElements()` which may potentially trigger `ClassCastException` at runtime.

Comment: I figured I could use some trick like that, however this seems a bit redundant, I was hoping there was another solution. I would like to ensure that the method in the concrete class always returns an element of its own type, and not another instance of `SomeAbstractType`

Comment: I've added another possibility, but it has its downsides.